# Generics using Enum in Java

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have an enum

```
public enum Days {
SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
```

}

I want to make a class which can take values of type Days. So I used Java Generics

```
public class State<T extend Days>
```

But there is an error

```
The type parameter T should not be bounded by the final type Days. 
Final types cannot be further extended
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use a generics bound. There's no need. Just use an unbounded type, like this:

```
public class State<T> {
    public State(T startState) {
        // whatever
    } 
}
```

And to use it:

```
State<Days> dayState = new State<>(Days.SUNDAY);
```

This is a straightforward typed class that doesn't need a bound.

The only bound that might make sense is a bound to an `enum`:

```
public class State<T extends Enum<T>> {
    public State(T startState) {
        // whatever
    } 
}
```

This version requires that the generic parameter be an `enum`. With this version the above usage example would still compile, but this would not compile (for example):

```
State<String> dayState = new State<>("hello");
```

because `String` is not an `enum`.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. OP wants to accept only Days, not anything at all or any enum. Not only he doesn't need a generics bound to do that, he doesn't need to use generics at all.

Comment: @Malcolm Well, he can use generics for his `State` class (as per my code). He just doesn't need the generic to be bounded. I see what you mean, but he *could* make his class generic - it seem like a handy class to have that deal with initial/current state

Comment: It doesn't serve the purpose the OP specified. He needs a class which operates on Days or its children: `I want to make a class which can take values of type days`. Since there are no children for any enum, he should write Days explicitly. Your code doesn't limit the values to Days.

Comment: It was useful to know that enums are final and therefore cannot be extended.

Comment: Also, you can do a few things to fix your problem:
1. Don't make State generic. Just use Days.
2. If you're going to define methods on Days, create an interface that Days implements. e.g. Days implements IDays; and class State<T extends IDays>;
3. Do as Bohemian suggests and use State<T extends Enum<T>>;

Answer (score 9):

enums are final types, which means, you can not extend from them

a generic like  wants a Class as Parameter which is Days or an extended class, but the extended class is not possible

so the only parameter possible is Days and you don't need a generic, if only one value is possible

Comment: -1 You are missing the point here. Any type is possible - it's a generic state class.

Comment: @Bohemian No, I think it is you who misses the point. See the comment to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot extend enums in java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html towards the end). Thus  is not possible.

-IF you need your class to work only with your enum you don't need generics

-if instead you need it to work with others enum (does it makes sense?) you don't need to specify the extend.

What does exactly your State class do ?

Answer (score 5):

The thing to do here is

```
public enum Days{..}

public class State { // no generic argument!
  ...
}
```

As it stands, you can't have `State<T extends Days>` because the only way to satisfy `T extends Days` is to have `T` *be* `Days`.  That's what it means for `Days` to be `final`.

So instead, you should make `State` *not* generic, and use `Days` directly everywhere you were trying to use `T`.  You can't declare `public class State<Days>`, because then it'll try to treat `Days` as a type *variable,* not as the class `Days`, and that's *not* what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This compiles fine for me under Java 6:

```
public enum Days {
  SUNDAY, 
  MONDAY, 
  TUESDAY, 
  WEDNESDAY,
  THURSDAY, 
  FRIDAY, 
  SATURDAY
}

public class State<T extends Days> {
  T state;

  public State(T startState) {
    this.state = startState;
  }
}

private void test() {
  State<Days> state = new State<Days> (Days.MONDAY);
}
```

However, if you want your `State` object to change from one `enum` to another you would be better to use something like:

```
public class State<S extends Enum<S>> {
  final ArrayList<S> states = new ArrayList<S>();
  private S state;

  public State(S startState) {
    states.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(startState.getClass()));
    this.state = startState;
  }

  public S next() {
    return state = states.get((state.ordinal() + 1) % states.size());
  }

  public S prev() {
    return state = states.get((state.ordinal() - 1 + states.size()) % states.size());
  }

  public S set(S newState) {
    return state = newState;
  }

  public S get() {
    return state;
  }
}

private void test() {
  State<Days> state = new State<Days> (Days.MONDAY);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `this.states = (S[])states.toArray();` throws a `ClassCastException`! I am working on a solution.

Comment: Fixed the `ClassCastException` issue!

Comment: @FBB - Yes but once you create a `State<E>` you can only ever use `E` states. `set(F)` will fail at compile time because `F` is not an `E` - this is the fundamental point of generics.

Comment: But this is useless, you can simply have a set(Days) method. See Louis Wasserman's answer.

Comment: @FBB - Agreed - but this does a `next` and `prev` for you.

Comment: This is not the question asked. Your `next` and `prev` methods could return a type `Days` all the same.